# visual studio 2015 wdk 10 command line error

Tags: exception, visual-studio-2015, wdk

I am following this guide

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439665(v=vs.85).aspx

I am using visual studio 2015 with wdk 10. However, when i am trying to build the solution (step 14), I get the following error:

`command-line error: exception handling option can be used only when compiling C++  in line 1`

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. There is a [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1623363/error-command-line-error-exception-handling-option-can-be-used-only-when-compiling-c) in VS 2015. You need to wait for VS 2015 Update 1, there is no workaround.

Answer (score 0):

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1623363/error-command-line-error-exception-handling-option-can-be-used-only-when-compiling-c

C++ is usually not used in kernel mode drivers because it is not supported.

I see this same issue with VS 2015. Just create a blank C file in your project and you will see the intellisense (~) at the first column of the first line. This means intellisense is essentially broken for all C source files now.